# Run python tests in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency

I tried to run my tests using pytest with [xdist](https://pytest.org/latest/xdist.html) in order to speed up my tests (that are very slow since most of them involve database transactions with SQLAlchemy). I launched them with:

`py.test -n 4`

(since my macbook pro has 4 cores)

As result, tests run in half the time previously required, but many of them fail (they pass if I run them normally).
So the problem seems to be that my code is not thread safe.
My question is: how can I create tests that can be safely executed in parallel, considering that my code does not explicitly makes use of threads and async code execution?
Is there a rule of thumb and/or special decorators/TestCases to use?
And moreover... why speed becomes 2x instead of 4x that I was expecting?

ps. I'm using Python 3.5.1 and all my tests inherit from `unittest.TestCase`

Comment: Could it be that your tests use different states of the same database, and they override the configuration of eachothers?

Comment: yep, that's the problem indeed, since in tearDown() I remove records in order to start with a clean table for each test

Comment: Then, you may need to have a separate table for each test (hint: use test "path" to suffix your table), then drop it in teardown.

Answer (score 0):

When creating unittest that can run in parallel you need to be careful how you use your `tearUp()` and `tearDown()` so you do isolate the unittests.